# How to split string into list of alphanumeric whose length is not same

Tags: python, regex

```
test_str = "1123456789ExampleDataEntryNumberOne2123456789ExampleDataEntryTwo"
```

i want to split above string in this form

```
['1123456789ExampleDataEntryNumberOne', '2123456789ExampleDataEntryTwo']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be solve using regular expression

```
import re
 
test_str = "1123456789ExampleDataEntryNumberOne2123456789ExampleDataEntryTwo"
res = list(filter(None,re.split("([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)", test_str)))

print (res)
```